# compiling alchemiapi application

Tags: c, linux

I have the following application which I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <libalchemyapi/alchemy_api.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char* html = NULL;
  if (ALCHEMY_OK != alchemy_global_init())
      alchemy_error_exit("Unable to initialize Alchemy API", NULL, html);
}
```

I'm compiling using:

```
gcc source.c -Llibs  -lalchemyapi
```

and I get:

> /tmp/ccngT1Ef.o: In function `main`:
>   source.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `alchemy_error_exit`
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Since the linker didn't complain about `alchemy_global_init`, I assume that you either misspelled `alchemy_error_exit`, or there is no such function.

Comment: It's a longshot but judging by this code [AlchemyAPI](https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_c/blob/master/example/keywords.c) the function `alchemy_error_exit` is in `utils.h` and not `alchemy_api.h`.

Comment: Yoda conditions do not use! Compilers since many years about the problems they catch warn.

Comment: utils.h did not resolve the problems, removing the conditional yields:
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libalchemyapi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
it compiles though.

Comment: this is not a problem with the compiler, but rather with the linker. So changing header files won't help. You may want to make sure that the function alchemy_error_exit is actually in that shared library alchemyapi, not in a supplementary library (I'm not familiar with the package, but look around for some library like alchemy_utils or alike)

Comment: Ive rmeoved that line, I get no problem with the linker the program compiles just fine but when I run that program I get:
 ./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libalchemyapi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory